# SwiftUI - How to apply markdown to TextEditor?

Tags: swiftui, markdown

With iOS 15 and Swift 5, I can add markdown to text, e.g

```
Text("Regular")
Text("*Italics*")
Text("**Bold**")
Text("~Strikethrough~")
Text("`Code`")
Text("[Link](https://apple.com)")
Text("***[They](https://apple.com) ~are~ `combinable`***")
```

But is it possible to somehow apply this to `TextEditor` as well? Can a user highlight some written text and apply specific markdown format to that text?

```
TextEditor(text: $notes) // how can $notes accept markdown here?
```

Comment: Please clarify - do you want the user to actually type markdown with symbols such as **, or do you want them to click a button that would then format the text?

Comment: Click a button that would format the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do this:

```
Text(content).lineLimit(nil)
```

Comment: Actually, as of 4/20/22, I don't think a user can select a subset of text in SwiftUI. Hopefully this is coming soon. However, for selecting all the content: .textSelection(.enabled)

Comment: I wish I could delete my comments. (Can I?)  Anyway, I also want what you describe which I believe is:  select a portion of text in a TextEditor (which IS possible), apply markdown, and see the results (bold, etc.) in the TextEditor.